# What happens to memory, when the Tab removes itself from Items collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-management

I'm going to use pseudocode in this question, so please, refer to this in theoretical aspect (I mean, there will be some simplifications)

Assume this situation:

I have **MainWindow** of my application, which has **TabControl**. In order to remove item from its collection, I'm using **static** function of **MainWindow** as follows:

```
public static void CloseTab(string someKindOfTabIdentity)
{
    var tab = myTabControl.Items.FirstOfDefault(someScenario);
    if (tab != null)
    {
        myTabControl.Items.Remove(tab);
        tab.Content = null;
        tab = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Now, I have **Page1**, where I allow user to close tab, via some function, let's say

```
private void GoToPage2()
{
    MainWindow.CreatePage2AddToTabControlAndNavigateToIt()
    MainWindow.CloseTab(myCurrentPage1Tab);
    App.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

This function should create new Tab, assign content to it and then, using `MainWindow.CloseTab(myCurrentPage1Tab);`, close current Tab, which contains **Page1**.

Here are questions:

1. What happens to memory alocation of **Page1** after `MainWindow.CloseTab(myCurrentPage1Tab);` line?
2. What happens to memory alocation of **Page1** if there is a code after `MainWindow.CloseTab(myCurrentPage1Tab);` line?
3. When **Page1** is going to be fully released from memory?
4. Is there any better (more efficient) way to achieve this?

This simplified scenario is what is happening to my WPF application all the time and I'm concerned if this is a safe way to manage tab items and memory of my app.

Comment: Removing a tab from your tab control doesn't means that your tab is unreferenced, has it is disposable, you should dispose the tab as well.

Comment: As a note, setting `tab = null` before calling `myTabControl.Items.Remove(tab)` does not make much sense, even in pseudocode.

Comment: @Clemens of course it doesnt, I will edit it, thx.

Comment: @LaurentLequenne could You please extend your answer?

Comment: I would recommend disposing the tab properly rather than just setting it to null. Setting it to null will work, however, it will take a while before the garbage collector kicks in and disposes it completely

Comment: GC.Collect() doesn't necessarily have to collect the object immediately for disposal. There are some exceptions. Please read the "Remarks" section of this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: GC.Collect() does not dispose objects. All winforms controls are using unmanaged resources and need to be disposed. If you are creating dynamically tabs or any other winform control you are adding Windows resources handlers which are limited. in amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The instance of `Page1` will become eligible for garbage collection provided that it's not referenced by any other object that is still alive.
2. Nothing additional, unless the "code after `MainWindow.CloseTab(myCurrentPage1Tab);` line" does something with the `Page1` reference that prevents the instance from being collected.
3. When the garbage collector has collected it. When this happens is nondeterministic, i.e. you don't really know when it happens and you shouldn't really care.
4. Well, there is no reason to explicitly call `GC.Collect`. This is almost always a bad idea. Provided that the instance of the `Page1` is no longer referenced in your application, it will be collected *eventually* anyway. Also, I don't know why you are using static methods but I guess that's another story.

To sum up, you should simply make sure that there are no references in your code that keeps the page alive longer than than necessary but stay out of way of the garbage collector.

Comment: Sadly, I have some `GC.Collect()` calls and for now I can't remove them. I've started several discussions here, on SO and on MSDN forums, about memory and memory leaks. Since my app suffer from bad memory allocation, I need, sometimes, to call GC...

Answer (score 0):

1-3

The garbage collector will remove unreferenced controls from memory when it gets round to doing so. Exactly when that happens will depend on what else your app is doing.

Exactly when some control is cleaned up by the collector doesn't usually matter.  If it does to you then maybe you have a problem in your design.

4

Depends what you're doing. Almost all dev teams use mvvm with wpf. The usual approach would be to bind a collection of viewmodels to the itemssource of that tabcontrol and template those out into tabs.  Removing a tab would involve removing a viewmodel out that list.

Only the current tab would be templated out into UI with this approach.

Your description makes this sound rather like navigation though. A common pattern used for mvvm style navigation is viewmodel first ( you should be able to google a bunch of examples ). Essentially this would involve exposing a property from a window viewmodel that would hold a viewmodel for current view. That would be bound to the content of a contentcontrol and templated into UI based on datatype.